# Null space of infinite dimensional linear operator connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Consider a linear operator $T$ of infinite dimensional, separable vector space $H$. $T$ has infinite dimensional kernel. Suppose $b=Tx$ with given vector $b$ has infinite many solutions(that is $T$ is not invertible), is the solution set $X$ connected? Or it depends on the given norm?

**Edit**:I forgot to mention the vector space is over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, Will this affect the result?

**Edit**:I make a huge mistake that my space is Hilbert space, but it is vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ now.

Comment: It's an affine subspace. Hence it's convex.

Comment: So convex vector space is connected?

Comment: What would "Hilbert space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$" mean?

Comment: I edited it, will this affect the result?

Comment: The weaker question what a norm on a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space would be remains. A topological vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ makes sense. But I suspect every nontrivial Hausdorff TVS over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is totally disconnected.